# Converting a raw data frame into workable time series

Tags: r, time-series

I have a spreadsheet documenting prices of 40 similar products at various dates. It looks like this.

```
date_1<-seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2011-01-01"), length.out = 40)
date_2<-seq(as.Date("2011-01-01"), as.Date("2012-01-01"), length.out = 40)
date_3<-seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"), as.Date("2013-01-01"), length.out = 40)
date_4<-seq(as.Date("2013-01-01"), as.Date("2014-01-01"), length.out = 40)
date_5<-seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2015-01-01"), length.out = 40)
date_6<-seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2016-01-01"), length.out = 40)

price_1<-floor(seq(20, 50, length.out = 40))
price_2<-floor(seq(20, 60, length.out = 40))
price_3<-floor(seq(20, 70, length.out = 40))
price_4<-floor(seq(30, 80, length.out = 40))
price_5<-floor(seq(40, 100, length.out = 40))
price_6<-floor(seq(50, 130, length.out = 40))

data.frame(date_1,price_1,date_2,price_2,date_3,price_3,date_4,price_4,date_5,price_5,date_6,price_6)
```

The problem is, the columns representing dates and prices alternate (convenient for record keeping). How can I transform the above data to a new dataframe consisting solely of prices of these 40 products as rows, with dates as column names? This will generate a lot of `NA`'s because the dates in each column differ but that's OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with time series data it is often helpful to have it in long form (one row per observation), even if your target output is wide (one row per time series).  Here are three possible approaches to get it into long form, then widen:

#### 1. base `reshape()`

To get long form, base `reshape` is definitely a powerful option.  The following solution improves on the accepted solution because it works for any numbers of products and observations and eliminates an unnecessary step:

```
df <- data.frame(date_1,price_1,date_2,price_2,date_3,price_3,
                 date_4,price_4,date_5,price_5,date_6,price_6)

# no need to create an id variable
long_form <- reshape(df, # idvar="id" by default
                     varying = list(grep('date_',names(df), value=TRUE), 
                                    grep('price_',names(df), value=TRUE) ),
                     v.names=c("date","price"),
                     direction="long",
                     sep="_")
```

And `reshape` can also widen it.  (We'll use `spread` in another approach below.)

```
wide_form <- reshape(long_form, drop='time', timevar='date', direction='wide')
```

#### 2. `data.table` `melt()` and `dcast()` (likely faster on real dataset)

Make sure you have `data.table` v1.9.6 or later, which allows you to melt multiple columns.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
melt.data.table(df[, prod_id := .I], # product id = original row number
                measure.vars = list(grep('date_',names(df), value=TRUE), 
                                    grep('price_',names(df), value=TRUE) ),
                variable.name = 'sequence',
                value.name = c('date','price'),
                id.vars = 'prod_id') -> long_form
```

In this case you don't use the sequence, so to get wide form is just:

```
dcast.data.table(long_form[, !'sequence', with=FALSE], 
                 value.var = 'price', # optional (function guesses correctly)
                 prod_id ~  date) -> wide_form
```

#### 3. `tidyr` & `dplyr` split-apply-combine (easy to understand)

It doesn't require the mental gymnastics that `reshape` does (at least for me).  It is a column-wise variant on the "split-apply-combine" paradigm.

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)

# Create long-form time series data
# Split table into sequenced prices and dates, then combine on product and sequence
full_join(
  df %>%
    select(starts_with('date_')) %>%      #~~~~ Left side = date component ~~~~~~~~
    mutate(prod_id = 1:nrow(df)) %>%      #~ product id = original row number     ~
    gather(sequence, date, -prod_id) %>%  #~ long form = 1 row per prod per seq   ~
    mutate(sequence =                     #~~~ Cols: product_id, sequence, date ~~~ 
            sub('^date_(\\d+)$', '\\1', sequence) )  ,   
  df %>%
    select(starts_with('price_')) %>%     #~~~ Right side = price component ~~~~~~~
    mutate(prod_id = 1:nrow(df)) %>%      #~                                      ~
    gather(sequence, price, -prod_id) %>% #~        same idea                     ~
    mutate(sequence =                     #~~ Cols: product_id, sequence, price ~~~
             sub('^price_(\\d+)$', '\\1', sequence) ) 
) -> long_form
```

In this case you don't need the sequence, so to get to wide form it's simply:

```
long_form %>% select(-sequence) %>% spread(date, price) -> wide_form
```

as noted by others above.

Comment: all three methods work very well to achieve the goal. I think I like `reshape` the best. Why do you think that long version is better than wide version of the table when working with time series? Any source you can refer me to?

Comment: @Oposum -- since a data.frame is a list of vectors, each having one atomic data type, it makes more sense (to me) to have all the dates (or timestamps) go into one col, all the prices (numeric) into another, all the product_id (integer) into a third, etc.  In your case the intervals are irregular, so if you are trying to `plot()` the price or seasonally adjust or something -- that info is lost if the date is a var name.  If you are using `ts()` or `zoo()`, it may be easier to create ts using the vectors of observations, the tradeoff being the possible need to subset based on product_id, etc.

Comment: @ C8H10N4O2 would the long version better handle the other problem I am experiencing with the wide version? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665648/substituting-dates-with-number-of-days-in-time-series/34666273

Comment: @Oposum probably, I'll take a look at it

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way I came up with using dplyr/tidyr packages:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
date_1<-seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2011-01-01"), length.out = 40)
date_2<-seq(as.Date("2011-01-01"), as.Date("2012-01-01"), length.out = 40)
date_3<-seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"), as.Date("2013-01-01"), length.out = 40)
date_4<-seq(as.Date("2013-01-01"), as.Date("2014-01-01"), length.out = 40)
date_5<-seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2015-01-01"), length.out = 40)
date_6<-seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2016-01-01"), length.out = 40)

price_1<-floor(seq(20, 50, length.out = 40))
price_2<-floor(seq(20, 60, length.out = 40))
price_3<-floor(seq(20, 70, length.out = 40))
price_4<-floor(seq(30, 80, length.out = 40))
price_5<-floor(seq(40, 100, length.out = 40))
price_6<-floor(seq(50, 130, length.out = 40))

df <- data.frame(date_1,price_1,date_2,price_2,date_3,price_3,date_4,price_4,date_5,price_5,date_6,price_6)

dates <- df[, grep('date', names(df))]
dates <- dates %>% gather(date_type, date) %>% select(-date_type)

prices <- df[, grep('price', names(df))]
prices <- prices %>% gather(price_type, price) %>% select(-price_type)

df <- cbind(dates, prices)
```

Then, to spread dates to columns and prices to rows, you can do something like this:

```
df <- arrange(df, price)
df <- spread(df, date, price)
```

Comment: thanks! having a problem installing `dplyr`on R version 3.1.0, will check your solution out as soon as I get it figured out

Comment: the problem is, your solution creates a table with two columns and 240 rows, one column is  the dates, and the other is all the prices. What I need though is a time series dataframe, where columns consisting of 40 rows of prices, and column names are dates. Transposing it would take care of dates as column names, but I need 40 rows for 40 different product variations. Otherwise it is not a time series table.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide sample output you are seeking? I can plot time series using the data frame created from above code like this: plot.ts(df$price) after arranging by date using df <- arrange(df, date).

Comment: I edited the question, the added code at the end will generate a sample table of what kind of output I am seeking.

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer with last two lines. Does that get you what you want?

Comment: not quite because there are still 240 rows, but should be 40. The columns are now correct though.

Comment: It is 240 rows (6 * 40) because if you do not persist the original product id into long form, `spread` can only assume that each observation belongs to a new item, instead of 6 observations per item.

Answer (score 2):

Using `baseR` and `tidyr` you could do:

```
 library(tidyr)
    #add an id to identify the products
    df$id=1:40

    #transform the data to a long format
    long_data <- reshape(df,idvar="id",varying=list(paste0("date_",1:6),paste0("price_",1:6)),v.names=c("date","price"),direction="long",sep="_")
    long_data <- long_data[,!grepl("time",colnames(long_data))]


    #put it back to a wide format
    wide_data <- spread(long_data,date,price)
```