# Functions for finding first and last variables in the vector

Tags: r, time-series

I am looking for an `R` function to find first and last variables in the vector similar to `min` for minimal and `max` for maximal. I know I can calculate the length of the vector, and go from there but it does not work for what I need it for.

I have a following dataset (in reality much larger):

```
a<-(c("2013-02-25","2013-03-13","2013-04-24","2013-05-12","2013-07-12","2013-08-11","actual_exam_date"))
b<-c(300,230,400,NA,NA,NA,"2013-04-30")
c<-c(NA,260,410,420,NA,NA,"2013-05-30")
d<-c(300,230,400,NA,370,390,"2013-08-30")
df<-as.data.frame(rbind(b,c,d))
colnames(df)<-a
rownames(df)<-(c("student 1","student 2","student 3"))
df$student_id <- row.names(df)
library('reshape2')
df2 <- melt(df, id.vars = c('student_id','actual_exam_date'),
                variable.name = 'pretest_date',
                value.name = 'pretest_score')
df2 <- df2[!is.na(df2$pretest_score),]
df2$actual_exam_date <- as.Date(df2$actual_exam_date)
df2$pretest_date <- as.Date(df2$pretest_date)
df2$days_before_exam <- as.integer(df2$actual_exam_date - df2$pretest_date)
df2$pretest_score <- as.numeric(df2$pretest_score)
df2
```

The way I was able to calculate the maximum scores for each student was this:

```
aggregate(pretest_score ~ student_id, df2, max)
```

Now I am looking to identify the first and last pretest scores for each student, to calculate the difference between them. Is there a way to do it using aggregate?

Comment: @Jilber if I subsetitute `max` with `head` or `tail` in `aggregate(pretest_score ~ student_id, df2, max)` in the above example, it produces three, not one column of pretest scores..not sure why

Comment: Now that I think about my answer I do not know why I guessed that the first and the last should be equal to the min and max... Even though you should be more precise about first and last. "First" and "last" in relation to the date or first and last row of the dateset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just another suggestion using `data.table` which allows you both order (if needed) and get the result without specifying anonymous functions and in a single line

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[order(pretest_date), diff(pretest_score[c(1, .N)]), keyby = student_id]
#    student_id  V1
# 1:  student 1 100
# 2:  student 2 160
# 3:  student 3  90
```

Answer (score 3):

First order your data by pretest date with

```
df2 <- df2[order(df2$pretest_date), ]
```

and then

```
aggregate(pretest_score ~ student_id, df2, function(x) tail(x, 1) - x[1])
  student_id pretest_score
1  student 1           100
2  student 2           160
3  student 3            90
```

Answer (score 3):

First value for each student

```
> aggregate(pretest_score ~ student_id, df2, head, 1)
  student_id pretest_score
1  student 1           300
2  student 2           260
3  student 3           300
```

Last value for each student

```
  > aggregate(pretest_score ~ student_id, df2, tail, 1)
      student_id pretest_score
    1  student 1           400
    2  student 2           420
    3  student 3           390
```

Comment: what does `,1` mean after `head` and `tail`?

Comment: @Oposum - It's the second argument to `head`/`tail`, passed through `aggregate()`.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways of doing what you are asking. With `dplyr` you can find the minimum and the maximum

```
 df2 %>% group_by(student_id) %>%
         filter(pretest_score == max(pretest_score) | pretest_score == min(pretest_score)) %>%
         mutate(differ = max(pretest_score) - min(pretest_score))
Source: local data frame [6 x 6]
Groups: student_id [3]

  student_id actual_exam_date pretest_date pretest_score days_before_exam differ
       (chr)           (date)       (date)         (dbl)            (int)  (dbl)
1  student 1       2013-04-30   2013-03-13           230               48    170
2  student 2       2013-05-30   2013-03-13           260               78    160
3  student 3       2013-08-30   2013-03-13           230              170    170
4  student 1       2013-04-30   2013-04-24           400                6    170
5  student 3       2013-08-30   2013-04-24           400              128    170
6  student 2       2013-05-30   2013-05-12           420               18    160
```

while with aggregate:

```
 aggregate(df2$pretest_score, list(df2$student_id), FUN = function(x) max(x) - min(x))
    Group.1   x
1 student 1 170
2 student 2 160
3 student 3 170
```

Comment: Doesn't look like it's about `min` or `max` to me.

Answer (score 2):

I think this one is easier with `tapply`:

```
tapply(df2$pretest_score, df2$student_id, function(x) tail(x,1)-head(x,1))

> student 1 student 2 student 3
        100       160        90
```